# Counting daily events on Pandas Time series

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a time series and would like to count how many events I have per day(i.e. rows in the table within a day). The command I'd like to use is:

```
ts.resample('D', how='count')
```

but "count" is not a valid aggregation function for time series, I suppose.

just to clarify, here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
0   2008-02-22 03:43:00
1   2008-02-22 03:43:00
2   2010-08-05 06:48:00
3   2006-02-07 06:40:00
4   2005-06-06 05:04:00
5   2008-04-17 02:11:00
6   2012-05-12 06:46:00
7   2004-05-17 08:42:00
8   2004-08-02 05:02:00
9   2008-03-26 03:53:00
Name: Data_Hora, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
ts.resample('D').count()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-86643e21ce18> in <module>()
----> 1 ts.resample('D').count()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base)
    255     def resample(self, rule, how=None, axis=0, fill_method=None,
    256                  closed=None, label=None, convention='start',
--> 257                  kind=None, loffset=None, limit=None, base=0):
    258         """
    259         Convenience method for frequency conversion and resampling of regular

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.pyc in resample(self, obj)
     98             return obj
     99         else:  # pragma: no cover
--> 100             raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex')
    101 
    102         rs_axis = rs._get_axis(self.axis)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

That can be fixed by turning the datetime column into an index with set_index. However  after I do that, I still get the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

because my Dataframe does not have a numeric column.

But I just want to count rows!! The simple "select count(*) group by ... " from SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get this to work, after removing the rows in which the index was NaT:

```
df2 = df[df.index!=pd.NaT]
```

I had to add a column of ones:

```
df2['n'] = 1
```

and then count only that column:

```
df2.n.resample('D', how="sum")
```

then I could visualize the data with:

```
plot(df2.n.resample('D', how="sum"))
```

Comment: At the moment, in pandas 0.18.1, the option `how` is deprecated.  [See here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#downsampling).
The suggested way would be `df2.n.resample('D').sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a one liner, using value counts and resampling.

Assuming your DataFrame is named `df`:

`df.index.value_counts().resample('D', how='sum')`

This method also works if datetime is not your index:

`df.any_datetime_series.value_counts().resample('D', how='sum')`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [104]: df = DataFrame(1,index=date_range('20130101 9:01',freq='h',periods=1000),columns=['A'])

In [105]: df
Out[105]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1000 entries, 2013-01-01 09:01:00 to 2013-02-12 00:01:00
Freq: H
Data columns (total 1 columns):
A    1000  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1)

In [106]: df.resample('D').count()
Out[106]: 
A    43
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is this the preferred way of doing it? `df.resample('D', how='count')` woks as well and is even recommended by the docs to use the string names of the functions since they can be faster.

Comment: they end up being exactly the same (e.g. call the same routines). I think using the function is *cleaner* IMO

Comment: I agree it's cleaner. The docs should be modified then... But kill me if I can remember where I read it :D

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex

Comment: The times need to be (1) set as the index and (2) correctly parsed as times, not just strings of times. See the docs to ``read_csv`` and/or ``pd.to_datetime``.

Comment: In my dataframe, the datetime column is not an index, and the set_index method fails to turn it into an index

Comment: Use ``ts = ts.set_index('your column name')`` or ``ts.set_index('your column name', inplace=True)``.

Comment: Thanks @DanAllan, I was missing the inplace=True argument. nevertheless I am still getting an error: ValueError: month must be in 1..12

Comment: It appears to be some invalid dates on my dataframe (which somehow survived the parser), now I have to find a way of removing these rows...

Comment: ``pd.to_datetime(dates_column,coerce=True)`` will force invalid to ``NaT``